# eclipse is not building my EAR correctly - sometimes it forgets the war, and always leaves out my library jars - why?

Tags: eclipse, deployment, jakarta-ee, glassfish, eclipse-wtp

I just upgraded to eclipse galileo from ganymede sr2 and now eclipse is doing a really bad job of building my EAR file during deployment.  There are several utility jars that are supposed to be included that it is completely ignoring, and there is a single war file that it only includes in the EAR occasionally.  Thus, when I deploy to glassfish I get errors like "File not found: blah.war" or if the war file is present, I get ClassNotFound errors.

Also, I'm trying to remove some EJB jars from the EAR but it still adds some of them back into the application.xml (it doesn't put them into the EAR as well, unfortunately).

I think eclipse is storing some extra metadata about the project somewhere outside of the EAR project and ignoring my changes to it, which is annoying.  However, I don't know where this is or how to "flush" it away.

Has anyone run into something like this?  Any idea how I could figure out what is really going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when redeploying, hopefully someone can shed some light on this, otherwise I'm going back to Ganymede...only way around it for me is to always delete the deployed EAR first then things are fine after that when I do a deploy...kind of stupid IMO.

Also getting bad memory leaks with galileo...system slows to a crawl after a few hours of usage, and lot more crashes vs Ganymede...sigh serves me right for jumping to a new version!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can read more about this in BugZilla:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=283184

I think they'll have a fix in the next release of WTP.